# How to find this discrete limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, discrete-logarithms, discrete-calculus

While proving some discrete Hardy-type inequalities I tried to prove the following limit for non-negative sequence $a(n)$ and $p>1$

$$\lim_{p\rightarrow1}\frac{1}{p-1}\left[\sum_{n=1}^{r}a(n)^{p}-\left(\sum_{n=1}^{r}a(n)\right)^{p}\right]=\sum_{n=1}^{r}a(
n)\log \frac{a( n) }{\sum_{n=1}^{r}a( n)}$$

Since the limit is $\frac{0}{0}$,  I tried to use Stolz–Cesàro Theorem but could not reach the result.
I will be very appreciative of any help.

Comment: Use L'Hopital's rule noting that $n^p = e^{p\log(n)}$

Comment: Is is also interesting to see that the negative of the expression inside the limit when $\sum_{n=1}^{r}a(n)=1$ corresponds to the $p$-[Tsallis entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsallis_entropy). So this computation shows that the limit of $p$-Tsallis entropy as $p\to 1$ is the Shannon entropy.

Comment: MBW: Actually, I used L'Hopital rule for the continuous case. But for the discrete case how you used the normal derivative for sequences!!

Comment: Sangchul Lee: Good notice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience, it is not hard to note that the equality is preserved when multiplying all elements of $a(n)$ by a fixed positive $\lambda$; thus, we can prove the result for sequences such that $\sum_{n=1}^{r} a(n) = 1$, and the result will follow for all other sequences. (This doesn't handle the case that $a$ is the zero sequence, but I assume that is impossible, due to the $\sum_{n=1}^{r} a(n)$ on the denominator of a fraction. And if one defines the RHS by continuity for this case, then the equality holds anyway.)

Now, in fact, this can be tackled directly by L'Hôpital's. We have all the necessary conditions.
$$
\lim_{p \to 1} \frac{\left(\sum_{n=1}^{r} a(n)^p\right) - 1^p}{p-1} = \lim_{p \to 1} \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{r} \log (a(n)) a(n)^p}{1} = \sum_{n=1}^{r} a(n)\log(a(n)).
$$

Comment: Actually, I used L'Hopital rule for the continuous case. But for the discrete case how you used the normal derivative for sequences!!

Comment: We're just differentiating the expression with regards to $p$, I'm not sure why the fact that $a(n)$ is a sequence really changes anything. All that matters is that it's constant in $p$. We can obviously interchange the sum and derivative because it's a finite sum.